# What is the -O5 flag for compiling gfortran .f90 files?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I see the flag in the documentation of how to compile some f90 code I have acquired (specifically, mpfi90 -O5 file.f90), but researching the -O5 flag turned up nothing in the gfortran docs, mpfi docs, or anywhere else. I assume it is an optimization flag like -O1, etc., but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: mpif90 is just a wrapper to another compiler. Are you sure you're using gfortran (or that the documentation uses gfortran)? f77 has an -O5 optimisation flag, for example.

Comment: As far as I remember, the gcc (which includes `gfortran`) is limited to `-O3`. Everything is above `3` is reduced to `3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlf91a.doc%2Fxlfug%2Fhu00509.htm

The flag `-O5` is an optimizer like `-O3` and `-O2`. The linked source says,

1. `qnoopt/-O0`    Fast compilation, debuggable code, conserved program
   semantics.
2. `-O2` (same as -O)    Comprehensive low-level optimization; partial debugging support.
3. `-O3` More extensive optimization; some precision trade-offs.
4. `-O4` and `-O5`   Interprocedural optimization; loop optimization; automatic machine tuning.

With each higher number containing all the optimizations of the lower levels.